# How does AWS-Sagemaker XGBoost perform compared to XGBoost installed locally?

Tags: xgboost, amazon-sagemaker

I did hyperparameter tuning on two XGBoost model -- one is the XGBoost in AWS-Sagemaker, the other is XGBoost installed locally using the same parameter range. It seems the optimized model via the former performs worse than the latter (18% less in prediction accuracy for a binary classification problem). I wonder has anyone encounter similar problem and if so, what would be the possible reasons? Thanks!

Comment: How many times you test and compare?

Comment: @BernardoCosta Just once, but the result is pretty solid. I just start to use SageMaker, so seeing decay in performance makes me quite disappointed and don't want to pursue further.

Comment: Have you used a fixed or a  random seed?

Comment: @bcosta12 I have used a random seed.

Comment: I recommend you to run again and compare... there is no reason but random seed to explain this difference. Try to run exactly the same seed, exactly the same dataset (without shuffling) and compare both results.

Comment: @bcosta12 Thanks! I will try it.